# Does the eigenvectors of a sub-block matrix are contained in the eigenvectors of the original matrix?

Tags: matrices

Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A>0$, one of its eigenvectors is $[x_1 \space x_2]^T>0$, 
and another $3 \times 3$ matrix $B=[A \space C, \space D \space e]$, where $C= [c_1 \space c_2]^T$ and $D=[d_1 \space d_2]$, $e$ is a positive number, meaning $A$ is the sub-block matrix of $B$, and one of $B$'s eigenvectors is $[y_1 \space y_2 \space y_3]^T$. And all the entries of $A$, $C$, $D$ and $e$ are positive.

Does $x_1$ and $x_2$ equal $y_1$ and $y_2$ correspondingly? In another words, the eigenvectors of $A$ can be contained in the eigenvectors of $B$? If so, how to prove that: $x_1=y_1, \space \space x_2=y_2$?

I saw this in some papers, and I can verify it by calculating some specific matrix, but I do not know how to prove it. Many thanks if you can help me to prove it.

Comment: Have you tried a few examples to see if the conjecture is true or not?

Comment: Yes, I tried several exapmles, and it turns out to be true..

Comment: That's strangle. This should be false for almost all examples.

Comment: I amended my question a little bit..

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not true. For a counterexample, consider
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&1&1\\ 1&1&2\\ \hline 1&2&3\end{array}\right].
$$
The submatrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 1&1\end{bmatrix}$ has two eigenspaces, one spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and the other spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}$. We have
$$
B\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2+z\\ 2+2z\\ 3+3z\end{bmatrix},
\quad B\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}z\\ 2z\\ -1+3z\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to see that $\begin{bmatrix}2+z\\ 2+2z\\ 3+3z\end{bmatrix}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ z\end{bmatrix}$ for any $z$.

Similarly, $\begin{bmatrix}z\\ 2z\\ -1+3z\end{bmatrix}$ is not a scalar multiple of $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\\ z\end{bmatrix}$.

So, vectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\\ z\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\\ z\end{bmatrix}$ or their scalar multiples are not eigenvectors of $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much first, then I double checked my question, the entries of A,C,D and e are all positive,also the eigenvector of A is positive, then it is true or not? For example, if all the entries of B are 1, then after calculation, the statement can be applied.

Comment: @Henry Your claim is still wrong in general. See my new edit for a concrete counterexample. If you generate $B$ at random, you should find that the claim does not hold in almost all cases. So, I don't understand why you keep getting positive results.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, maybe it is coincident that I keep getting the positive results, but your counterexample is undeniable.

Answer (score 0):

Using definitions, if $x$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $Ax = \lambda x$. Then

$\left[\begin{matrix}A & C \\ D & e\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}x \\ z\end{matrix}\right]  = \left[\begin{matrix}Ax + Cz \\ Dx + ez\end{matrix}\right] $.

If $z\in \text{nullspace}(C)$ and $Dx + ez = \lambda z$ then this is true. If, in addition, $x\in \text{nullspace}(D)$, then you can pick $z = 0$ and $\left[\begin{matrix}x \\ z\end{matrix}\right]$ is an eigenvector of $B$. But in general, no matter what the signs of the subblocks are, it may not work.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, as you said this statement may not work in general.